# iPhone: How do I convert a string with a currency symbol to a negative number?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

Say I have a string which is £23.56 or $23.56 how can I convert it into -23.56 ?

I have this part

```
NSMutableString *strAmount = [NSMutableString stringWithString:txtAmount.text];
[strAmount replaceCharactersInRange: [strAmount rangeOfString: strCurrencySymbol]  withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a good start. You could use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`instead of `rangeOfString:` though after creating a set of currency symbols. Your code could look like this:

```
NSMutableString *strAmount = [NSMutableString stringWithString:txtAmount.text];
NSCharacterSet *currencySet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$€£"];
[strAmount replaceCharactersInRange: [strAmount rangeOfCharacterFromSet:currencySet]  withString:@"-"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNumberFormatter`

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setLenient:YES];

NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:@"£23.56"];

NSDecimalNumber *minusOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"-1.00"];
NSDecimalNumber *money = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[number decimalValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *negativeMoney = [money decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:minusOne];

NSLog(@"£23.56 is now %@", [negativeMoney description]);
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning on that...

warning: 'NSDecimalNumber' may not respond to '-descriptionWithLocale'

Also an error -[NSDecimalNumber descriptionWithLocale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x595cde0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber descriptionWithLocale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x595cde0'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: sorry about that. last statement is updated to use just `description`